# Messages lost and message order changed even after using SM in ejabberd-15.11

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I am working on chat app using `ejabberd-15.11`, `mod_offline` enabled and stream management is also enabled and client side using `smack 4.1` with Stream Management enabled but message lost the scenario is:

**A** sends message to **B** before receiving message **B** turns off wi-fi or disconnects from network, but ejabberd server show status online if B comes online again get offline message but not all messages.Message get lost and its order also changed. My ejabberd_c2s configuration is as

```
port: 5222
module: ejabberd_c2s
certfile: "/opt/ejabberd-15.11/conf/server.pem"
starttls: true
stream_management: true
resend_on_timeout: true
max_ack_queue: 1000
resume_timeout: 300
timeout: 1000
## To enforce TLS encryption for client connections,
## use this instead of the "starttls" option:
## starttls_required: true
##
## Custom OpenSSL options
##
```

And also i do not want to use mod_ping  because it will take server resources and will sucks mobile battery. client log is below-

```
<r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1256' type='chat'><body>Msg 1</body><x xmlns='jabber:x:event'><offline/><delivered/><displayed/><composing/></x><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:08.814Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1257' type='chat'><body>Msg 2</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:08.859Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1259' type='chat'><body>Msg 3</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:08.859Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1260' type='chat'><body>Msg 4</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:08.907Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1263' type='chat'><body>Msg 5</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:08.907Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1264' type='chat'><body>Msg 6</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:08.908Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1265' type='chat'><body>Msg 7</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:08.954Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1269' type='chat'><body>Msg 8</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:08.955Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1270' type='chat'><body>Msg 9</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:08.957Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1271' type='chat'><body>Msg 10</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:09.010Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1275' type='chat'><body>Msg 11</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:09.010Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1276' type='chat'><body>Msg 12</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:09.058Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1279' type='chat'><body>Msg 13</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:09.579Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1281' type
02-03 13:28:47.953    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='4'/>
02-03 13:28:47.956    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='5'/>
02-03 13:28:47.959    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <message to='917575757575@chatserver.com' id='0kLtJ-789'><received xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts' id='4dmc8-1256'/></message>
02-03 13:28:47.960    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>
02-03 13:28:47.960    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='6'/>
02-03 13:28:47.964    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='7'/>
02-03 13:28:47.966    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='8'/>
02-03 13:28:47.969    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='9'/>
02-03 13:28:47.969    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='10'/>
02-03 13:28:47.971    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='11'/>
02-03 13:28:47.972    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='12'/>
02-03 13:28:47.976    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='13'/>
02-03 13:28:47.977    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='14'/>
02-03 13:28:47.985    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='15'/>
02-03 13:28:47.990    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='16'/>
02-03 13:28:47.990    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='17'/>
02-03 13:28:47.992    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='18'/>
02-03 13:28:47.994    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='19'/>
02-03 13:28:47.998    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='20'/>
02-03 13:28:48.002    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='21'/>
02-03 13:28:48.006    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='22'/>
02-03 13:28:48.008    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='23'/>
02-03 13:28:48.009    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='24'/>
02-03 13:28:48.012    6529-8270/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? RECV (5): <r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1297' type='chat'><body>Msg 22</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:09.775Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1298' type='chat'><body>Msg 23</body><x xmlns='jabber:x:event'><offline/><delivered/><displayed/><composing/></x><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:09.776Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1299' type='chat'><body>Msg 24</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:09.822Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1303' type='chat'><body>Msg 25</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:09.823Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1304' type='chat'><body>Msg 26</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:09.870Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1307' type='chat'><body>Msg 27</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:09.870Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1308' type='chat'><body>Msg 28</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:09.871Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1309' type='chat'><body>Msg 29</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:09.919Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1313' type='chat'><body>Msg 30</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:09.919Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1314' type='chat'><body>Msg 31</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:09.967Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1317' type='chat'><body>Msg 32</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:09.967Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1318' type='chat'><body>Msg 33</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:09.971Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1319' type='chat'><body>Msg 34</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.018Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1
02-03 13:28:48.012    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='25'/>
02-03 13:28:48.014    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='26'/>
02-03 13:28:48.015    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='27'/>
02-03 13:28:48.016    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='28'/>
02-03 13:28:48.017    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='29'/>
02-03 13:28:48.023    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='30'/>
02-03 13:28:48.024    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='31'/>
02-03 13:28:48.028    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='32'/>
02-03 13:28:48.032    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='33'/>
02-03 13:28:48.032    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='34'/>
02-03 13:28:48.032    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='35'/>
02-03 13:28:48.033    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='36'/>
02-03 13:28:48.035    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='37'/>
02-03 13:28:48.037    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <message to='917575757575@chatserver.com' id='0kLtJ-822'><received xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts' id='4dmc8-1257'/></message>
02-03 13:28:48.047    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>
02-03 13:28:48.047    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='38'/>
02-03 13:28:48.047    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='39'/>
02-03 13:28:48.048    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='40'/>
02-03 13:28:48.048    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='41'/>
02-03 13:28:48.055    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='42'/>
02-03 13:28:48.060    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='43'/>
02-03 13:28:48.064    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='44'/>
02-03 13:28:48.068    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='45'/>
02-03 13:28:48.074    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='46'/>
02-03 13:28:48.078    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='47'/>
02-03 13:28:48.082    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='48'/>
02-03 13:28:48.085    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='49'/>
02-03 13:28:48.088    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='50'/>
02-03 13:28:48.090    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='51'/>
02-03 13:28:48.092    6529-8270/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? RECV (5): ne Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1350' type='chat'><body>Msg 49</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.335Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1353' type='chat'><body>Msg 50</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.335Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1354' type='chat'><body>Msg 51</body><x xmlns='jabber:x:event'><offline/><delivered/><displayed/><composing/></x><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.378Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1357' type='chat'><body>Msg 52</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.378Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1358' type='chat'><body>Msg 53</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.381Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1359' type='chat'><body>Msg 54</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.425Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1363' type='chat'><body>Msg 55</body><x xmlns='jabber:x:event'><offline/><delivered/><displayed/><composing/></x><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.425Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1364' type='chat'><body>Msg 56</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.432Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1365' type='chat'><body>Msg 57</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.485Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1369' type='chat'><body>Msg 58</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.485Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1370' type='chat'><body>Msg 59</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.529Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1373' type='chat'><body>Msg 60</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.529Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1374' type='chat'><body>Msg 61</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.580Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><mes
02-03 13:28:48.093    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='52'/>
02-03 13:28:48.096    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='53'/>
02-03 13:28:48.102    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='54'/>
02-03 13:28:48.102    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='55'/>
02-03 13:28:48.107    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='56'/>
02-03 13:28:48.109    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='57'/>
02-03 13:28:48.110    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='58'/>
02-03 13:28:48.113    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='59'/>
02-03 13:28:48.118    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='60'/>
02-03 13:28:48.121    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='61'/>
02-03 13:28:48.127    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='62'/>
02-03 13:28:48.129    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='63'/>
02-03 13:28:48.132    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='64'/>
02-03 13:28:48.135    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='65'/>
02-03 13:28:48.139    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='66'/>
02-03 13:28:48.143    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='67'/>
02-03 13:28:48.144    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='68'/>
02-03 13:28:48.146    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='69'/>
02-03 13:28:48.152    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='70'/>
02-03 13:28:48.155    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='71'/>
02-03 13:28:48.159    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='72'/>
02-03 13:28:48.159    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='73'/>
02-03 13:28:48.163    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='74'/>
02-03 13:28:48.166    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='75'/>
02-03 13:28:48.169    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='76'/>
02-03 13:28:48.172    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='77'/>
02-03 13:28:48.175    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='78'/>
02-03 13:28:48.177    6529-8270/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? RECV (5): /body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.814Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1403' type='chat'><body>Msg 76</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.862Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1407' type='chat'><body>Msg 77</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.909Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1409' type='chat'><body>Msg 78</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.909Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1410' type='chat'><body>Msg 79</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.909Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1411' type='chat'><body>Msg 80</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.961Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1415' type='chat'><body>Msg 81</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.961Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1416' type='chat'><body>Msg 82</body><x xmlns='jabber:x:event'><offline/><delivered/><displayed/><composing/></x><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:10.961Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1417' type='chat'><body>Msg 83</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:11.005Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1421' type='chat'><body>Msg 84</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:11.005Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1422' type='chat'><body>Msg 85</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:11.049Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1425' type='chat'><body>Msg 86</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:11.049Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1426' type='chat'><body>Msg 87</body><x xmlns='jabber:x:event'><offline/><delivered/><displayed/><composing/></x><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com' stamp='2016-02-03T07:58:11.098Z'>Resent, Offline Storage</delay></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><message from='917575757575@chatserver.com/Smack' to='919090909090@chatserver.com' xml:lang='en' id='4dmc8-1429' type='chat'><body>Msg 88</body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='chatserver.com'
02-03 13:28:48.179    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='79'/>
02-03 13:28:48.181    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='80'/>
02-03 13:28:48.185    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='81'/>
02-03 13:28:48.188    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='82'/>
02-03 13:28:48.193    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='83'/>
02-03 13:28:48.199    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='84'/>
02-03 13:28:48.202    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='85'/>
02-03 13:28:48.205    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='86'/>
02-03 13:28:48.209    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='87'/>
02-03 13:28:48.216    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='88'/>
02-03 13:28:48.221    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='89'/>
02-03 13:28:48.222    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='90'/>
02-03 13:28:48.223    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <message to='917575757575@chatserver.com' id='0kLtJ-876'><received xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts' id='4dmc8-1259'/></message>
02-03 13:28:48.225    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>
02-03 13:28:48.225    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='91'/>
02-03 13:28:48.226    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='92'/>
02-03 13:28:48.227    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='93'/>
02-03 13:28:48.228    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='94'/>
02-03 13:28:48.229    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='95'/>
02-03 13:28:48.230    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='96'/>
02-03 13:28:48.236    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='97'/>
02-03 13:28:48.236    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='98'/>
02-03 13:28:48.237    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='99'/>
02-03 13:28:48.239    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='100'/>
02-03 13:28:48.243    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='101'/>
02-03 13:28:48.244    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='102'/>
02-03 13:28:48.247    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='103'/>
02-03 13:28:48.249    6529-8269/com.example.mchat D/SMACK? SENT (5): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='104'/>
```

Comment: You probably need to provide more details on the workflow on your clients, logs at the XMPP level.

Comment: If I set resume_timeout = 0 then its working fine but this setting is correct or not right now I am not very much sure? Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: We would need more detailed client log at XMPP level and or ejabberd debug log level to understand your case.

Comment: Any option to share the XMPP traffic logs or ejabberd server logs in debug mode showing the issue ?

Comment: yes i have shared client log above.

Comment: Thanks, we will check, as it could be a bug.